# How can I invoke a method as soon as a bool flag changes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to perform `[document doSomething]` as soon as `[document isBusy]` is false. What is the best way to do it? I tried it with a while-loop but that delays the following code, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If the action a semantic of your document model**

From your question both `isBusy` and `doSomething` are features of your document and the action to `doSomething` when `isBusy` goes false is appears to be a *semantic of your document model* and should therefore be implemented *by your document model*, i.e. something like:

```
- (void) setIsBusy:(BOOL)flag
{
   if(flag != _isBusy) // check if this is a change
   {
      _isBusy = flag;
      if(flag)
      {
         // doSomething, or schedule doSomething if it is a long operation etc., e.g.
         [self doSomething];
      }
   }
}
```

Using KVO to implement semantics *within* a single object is probably unusual, but there are cases where it is useful. In this case it would replace a direct action with an indirect one - KVO would execute `doSomething` at exactly the same point as the above sample code, there would just be a number of intermediate system methods between `setIsBusy` and `doSomething` plus the associated overhead of setting up the KVO.

**If the action is a semantic of your document's client**

Of course, if the linkage between these two is independent of your document model, i.e. is a *semantic of the client* of your document, then KVO is appropriate and would be *implemented in your client*. Your client would register as an observer of your document, i.e. something like:

```
[document addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"isBusy"
              options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
              context:NULL];
```

in a method of the client. Then in your client when  a notification of the change is received take the appropriate action:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
   if ([keyPath isEqual:@"isBusy"] && object == document)
      [document doSomething;
   else
      [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                           ofObject:object
                             change:change
                            context:context];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `isBusy` has a associated setter method, you can call `doSomething` in that setter. A better option would be to use [Key Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/) to observe the value of `isBusy` and take action when it changes.

Answer (score 2):

Use KVC/KVO (Key Value Coding and Key Value Observation).  The subject is covered well in the Apple Documentation.  KVO and KVC is a basic programming technique which provides may solutions to your problem.